# A book on Emmy Noether's life

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a good book on Noether's life. Not only a biography, but a book that also explains her life's work to a general, somewhat mathematically mature audience. If such a book is not available, then a book aimed at graduate students would be the next best thing.

Comment: MBW Tent, [Emmy Noether: The Mother of Modern Algebra](https://books.google.it/books?id=RmY_Cq9MNCcC) (2008) and see the [review](http://www.ams.org/notices/200909/rtx090901105p.pdf)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Seems right for me.

Comment: That book by Tent is not good as a real source on Noether's life. It is aimed at young children and has fictional stories. The funniest thing is the cover, which is a woman who is most definitely *not* Emmy Noether, so the cover is fictional too. When I saw that book for sale at a math meeting I was startled at how such an error could happen. The explanation can be read at http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~ci3/noetherphoto-engl.pdf. If you want an account of her life and mathematical work, why not look at http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Noether_Emmy.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Emmy Noether's Wonderful Theorem](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0801896940) by Dwight E. Neuenschwander.

The title says it all: the book explains Noether's theorem in detail. Everything is derived and explained from scratch: the action principle, symmetries, Lagrangians, Hamiltonians,... The style very reader-friendly, it is not a textbook. However, the book is only meant for those who have enough mathematical background (in particular maths and physics undergrads). The introduction contains a short (4-page) biography.

Comment: According to a recent-ish article in the *Bulletin of the AMS* this book is historically quite inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

Some books about Emmy Noether:

1. [A. Dick: *Emmy Noether 1882-1935*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1468405373)
2. [M. B. W. Tent: *Emmy Noether, The Mother of Modern Algebra*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568814305)
3. [D. E. Neuenschwander: *Emmy Noether's Wonderful Theorem*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0801896940)
4. [Y. Kosmann-Schwarzbach: *The Noether Theorems, Invariance and Conservation Laws in the Twentieth Century*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038787867X)

The first two is more biographical, the last two contain formal details too.